# std::ifstream closed for some reason?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open ifstreams that will contain file data, that can be read from later on. I'm trying to pass a vector of ifstreams into a constructor, but for some reason when I loop through the vector, all the references are closed. But, the other variables (data stream and meta stream) remain open.

What am I missing here? I'm coming from a very heavy Java background, so I'm still learning C++

**FileStore.h**

```
//
// Created by Tom on 8/16/2017.
//

#ifndef CFS_FILESTORE_H
#define CFS_FILESTORE_H

#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include "ByteBuffer.h"

class FileStore {

private:
    std::ifstream *data_stream;
    std::vector<std::ifstream *> index_streams;
    std::ifstream *meta_stream;

public:
    FileStore(std::ifstream *data, std::vector<std::ifstream *> indexes, std::ifstream *meta);
    ~FileStore() = default;

    int get_type_count();
    ByteBuffer read(int type, int id);
    int get_file_count(int type);

    static FileStore open(std::string &root);
};


#endif //CFS_FILESTORE_H
```

**FileStore.cpp**

```
//
// Created by Tom on 8/16/2017.
//

#include "FileStore.h"

FileStore::FileStore(std::ifstream *data, std::vector<std::ifstream *> indexes, std::ifstream *meta)
        : data_stream(data), index_streams(std::move(indexes)), meta_stream(meta) {

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Data Open : " << data_stream->is_open() << std::endl;
    std::cout  << "Meta Open : " << meta_stream->is_open() << std::endl;

    for (auto v : index_streams) {
        std::cout << "Index Open : " << v->is_open() << std::endl;
    }
}

int FileStore::get_type_count() {
    return 0;
}

ByteBuffer FileStore::read(int type, int id) {
    return ByteBuffer();
}

int FileStore::get_file_count(int type) {
    return 0;
}

FileStore FileStore::open(std::string &root) {
    std::ifstream data(root + "main_file_cache.dat2");
    if (!data.good())
        throw std::runtime_error("data file does not exist.");

    std::vector<std::ifstream *> indexes;
    for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++) {
        std::ifstream index(root + "main_file_cache.idx" + std::to_string(i));
        if (!index.good())
            break;

        indexes.push_back(&index);
    }

    std::ifstream meta(root + "main_file_cache.idx255");
    if (!meta.good())
        throw std::runtime_error("meta file does not exist.");

    return FileStore(&data, indexes, &meta);
}
```

**Output**

```
Data Open : true
Meta Open : true
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
Index Open : false
```

Comment: each `index` is being destroyed at the end of their scope, rendering the pointers to them invalid

Answer (score 2):

```
    std::ifstream index(root + "main_file_cache.idx" + std::to_string(i));
```

This constructs a `std::ifstream` object. It gets declared with automatic scope.

```
    indexes.push_back(&index);
}
```

This pushes a pointer to the `std::ifstream` into the `indexes` vector, however because `index`'s automatic scope ends immediately afterwards, the `index` object gets immediately destroyed, with its corresponding file being closed. You declared this `std::ifstream` object in automatic scope, inside the inner loop. As such, the object gets destroyed at the end of the loop.

The subsequent code then attempts to dereference these pointers, that were stored in the `indexes` vector, which are now all dangling pointers. This results in undefined behavior.

Additionally, the `indexes` vector gets passed by value, which results in the vector getting copied, which adds to confusion.

You need to re-read the following chapters in your C++ book:

- The chapter that explains how automatic scope, and how dynamic scope works in C++.
- The chapter that explains the difference between passing function arguments by reference and passing them by value, and what that means.

Answer (score 0):

each `index` is being destroyed at the end of their scope, rendering the pointers to them invalid

```
std::vector<std::ifstream *> indexes;
for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++) {
    std::ifstream index(root + "main_file_cache.idx" + std::to_string(i));
    if (!index.good())
        break;

    indexes.push_back(&index);
} // index is destroyed here
```

you should change it to create them with `new` (just make sure you delete them when you're done)

```
std::vector<std::ifstream *> indexes;
for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++) {
    std::ifstream* index = new std::ifstream(root + "main_file_cache.idx" + std::to_string(i));
    if (!index->good())
        break;

    indexes.push_back(index);
}
```

or better yet, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>>` and `std::make_unique` instead.

You'll likely have the same problem with `meta` and `data` when you return from `open`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is the solution I came up with. This, so far seems to be giving me the output I desire

https://gist.github.com/tomlegodais/c811f086eb5fa7783d4fdf4dfa8e547b